# How to tell pelican to not generate some pages?

Tags: pelican

I use some "partial" content in md files. For example my "about" page has:  `% include "partners.html" %}`, the partner.html template calls:

```
{% for p in pages|selectattr("title", "eq", "Partners") %}
    <h1>{{ p.title }}</h1>
    <div class="partners-profiles">
        {{ p.content }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

so it looks for `partners.md` file content, which is provided in pages.

This has a downside: Pelican generates `/partners` page, that I don't need.

Is there a way to avoid it?